# 2 ajax forms on the same page posting same textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Is it possible to post, say like a value in a textbox, to 2 different ajax forms that are on the same page? It doesn't have to be at the same time?

What I'm trying to do is this: I have a search page that searches for customers and displays them on a paged grid. Users can specify up to 5 parameters (5 textboxes) to narrow the search.

On the same page I have an export option. Well since I want all the customers for the search and not just the paged data I need a way to post back to the server for this option passing the same parameters used in the grid.

I'm using a ViewModel which would be nice if I can pass that back to the server rather than the individual search fields that are backed by the view model.

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing AJAX requests, we can safely assume that JS is allowed ;)

Thus, use jQuery (or another JS library) to perform the AJAX postbacks, and just post to different urls.

```
function postTo(url) {
    $.post(
        url,
        $('#theForm').serialize(),
        function(returnData) {
            // do this on success
        }
    );
}
```

Then, just hook up two different calls to this method to your submit links/buttons:

```
$(function() {
    $('#searchButton').click(function() {
        postTo('/search/');
    });

    $('#exportButton').click(function() {
        postTo('/export/');
    });
});
```

**EDIT** in response to follow-up questions in comments:

Q1) How can the controller parse `$('#theForm').serialize()` to a `ViewModel` object?

A1) This is all part of the ASP.NET MVC model binding, and has nothing to do with the jQuery code. all `.serialize()` does with the form is to line up its names and values in a querystring-like format, so that `data` on the JSON object will end up something like `'textbox1=first value&textbox2=second value'` etc for all form values. This works the same way as a regular POST request, so ASP.NET MVC doesn't need to handle it any differently than a regular, non-AJAX request.

Q2) Can the controller return entity object and can the callback read it?

A2) You can serialize most objects to JSON using `return Json(...)` in your controller, but returning and entity object (which I assume is then from Entity Framework) is not recommended. It is much better to have a data transfer object (DTO) that only has the necessary properties.
As for the callback, the ASP.NET MVC model binders can recognize any object as long as the input data is correctly formatted.

Comment: Would my form element be <form>, <% html.beginform %> or <% ajax.beginform %>

Comment: @rod: What really matters is the rendered output. I doubt that any of them pose any problems, but since you're not going to use the functionality of `<% Ajax.BeginForm() %>` anyway, I'd recommend using a `<% Html.BeginForm() %>` with options that gracefully fall back on the behavior you want on non-javascript enabled browsers.

Comment: Apparently $('#theForm').serialize() can show up on the controller as a parameter of type ViewModel? How does it know?

Comment: Can the controller return an entity object and can the call back read it?

Comment: Will someone see this even if I have checked answered or should I repost last 2 questions in comments above?

Comment: @rod: I see all comments on my posts, whether accepted or not. In response to your questions, see my edit.

Comment: @Tomas - I sent back a business dto object from the controller and tried to read it in the callback. It labled it as a business but I couldn't drill down into properties.

Comment: @rod - By default, I believe the model binder only binds one level. I am unable to find any evidence of that at the moment, but I'm pretty sure I've seen a blog post somewhere outlining why this is so, and how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to post back.  You can build the model in javascript from any fields you like and post to any controller / action you like.

```
        $.post("/Articles/jQueryAddComment",
 { commentText: commentText, id: id, type: commentType }, function(newCommentListHTML) {
        });
```